# Object reference error while using ngWebDriver(protractor) and driver(Selenium) in same method

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, protractor-net

My application having Angular and Non Angular web pages. For Angular pages i am using nuget protractor-net.

In my test case when i use ngWebDriver and Selenium webdriver, i am getting Error - System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Actual Result: Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
private IWebDriver driver;
private NgWebDriver ngDriver;

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Users\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32");
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
ngDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);
ngDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'Login')]")).Click();

//Once i click on above button, re-directed to non angular page.

driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys("test");
```

For angluar pages it is working fine ngDriver, but when i use driver i got error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already declared the `driver` using `private IWebDriver driver;` You dont need to again declare a new `driver` while initialising it like you are doing in the line: `IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Users\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32");`

You just need to do initialise the same driver which you have declared at the global level like:

```
private IWebDriver driver;
driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Users\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32");
```